# Automated Notification User Strategy

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, cron, sidekiq

I have a case to automated notification for user apps (android apps), which is

1. After Install Application and before or no registration after that.
2. After Registration and no action after that.
3. After Ask Question and no action after that.

Each section has flexible time 'after' (e.g after 1 hour that, after 1 day that, after 3 day that etc).

I'm back-end developer, For scheduler I'm using sidekiq, cron (whenever) and currently using firebase for notification now. For now I have only two strategies

1. Sidekiq

   Throw each action to job for every user.

   Problem :

   - buildup on the queue because I have tweenty background job now.
   - Currently I'm using 3 (load balancer) servers and sidekiq - redis on each server. I can't stop/find some job given to sidekiq (e.g after install section job at server X) when a user register after install at server Y.
2. Cron

   Add a cronjob and set schedule every 1 hour to query each action

   Problem :

   - need More  work in the query every 1 hour
   - schedules will not be appropriate given the flexible time.

Should I use one from above or need an another best way to do that?

Comment: How many users are there?

Comment: @c0de222 20.000 installers/day, 17.000 registars/day

Comment: I would put everything in sidekiq without worrying about queue length for now. If the installers increase to 10K per day then I would go with below mentioned answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would put all the 1 hour in sidekiq and the 1 day, 3 days in a cron job which will run daily once.